# Intellij IDEA 2018.1 - Disable simple comment folding

Tags: intellij-idea, editor, folding

Using `IntelliJ 2018.1` I noticed that on **certain** files multi-line simple comments are always folded:

```
// My multi
// line
// comment
```

becomes

```
//...
```

How do I turn it off? I need to always see my comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings | Editor | General | Code Folding | [ ] End of line comments sequence

Comment: Thanks. This did the trick. I don't understand the "End of line..." thing. Probably it's because I'm not a native english speaker